# Submersion function from a product space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, smooth-manifolds, submersions

Let $\Phi(x,y) \colon U_N \times U_M \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be a submersion, where $U_N \subset  \mathbb{C}^N$ and $U_M \subset \mathbb{C}^M$.

1. Under which condition on $\Phi$ can I find some $s \in \mathbb{C}^N$ such that $\Phi(s, \cdot) \colon \mathbb{C}^M \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is a submersion?
2. In that case, when is the set of such $s \in \mathbb{C}^N$ the complement of a set of measure zero?

Note that 1 is is not true in general, for example take $f(x,y)=x^2-y$.

(For the second question I tried to use Sard's theorem, but I got a bit stuck...)